# FileNotFoundException in FileAppender of Log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, regression

I am getting FileNotFoundException below is the full error log:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/workspace/**/addUserNoDefaultRole.log (No such file or directory)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:158)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.<init>(FileAppender.java:110)
at com.scene7.api.apiclient.ProcessingNode.getLogger(ProcessingNode.java:217)
at com.scene7.api.apiclient.ProcessingNode.getLogger(ProcessingNode.java:227)
at com.scene7.api.apiclient.ProcessingNode.getLogger(ProcessingNode.java:227)
at com.scene7.api.apiclient.RequestSetNode.process(RequestSetNode.java:51)
at com.scene7.api.apiclient.ContainerNode.processChildren(ContainerNode.java:21)
at com.scene7.api.apiclient.IncludeNode.process(IncludeNode.java:90)
at com.scene7.api.apiclient.ContainerNode.processChildren(ContainerNode.java:21)
at com.scene7.api.apiclient.ContainerNode.process(ContainerNode.java:16)
at com.scene7.api.apiclient.ApiClient.processScript(ApiClient.java:58)
at com.scene7.api.regression.ApiClientCallable.call(ApiClientCallable.java:18)
at com.scene7.api.regression.ApiClientCallable.call(ApiClientCallable.java:7)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

My code to call getLogger() is as following:

```
public Logger getLogger() {
    if (this.logger != null) {
        return this.logger;
    } else if (getAttributeValue(OUTPUT_FILE_ATTR_QNAME) != null) {
        try {
            String outputFile = getAttributeValue(OUTPUT_FILE_ATTR_QNAME);
            File file = new File(outputFile);
            outputFile = file.getCanonicalPath();
            this.logger = Logger.getLogger(outputFile);
            this.logger.setAdditivity(false);
            Layout layout = new PatternLayout(ProcessingNode.logPattern);
            FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender(layout, outputFile, false);
            fileAppender.setEncoding("UTF-8");
            this.logger.addAppender(fileAppender);
            this.logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);

            return this.logger;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    } else if (this.parent != null) {
        return this.parent.getLogger();
    }

    return null;
}
```

My log4j.properties are as follows:

```
    log4j.rootLogger=WARN, R
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.base}/logs/defaultLog4j.log
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

I am going to execute my test cases with a thread pool of size 10, and this issue is occurring intermittently, which means some test cases will pass, and few test cases are going through Abobe Exception.
I am using `log4j1.1.3`

Work around:
I checked the log4j FileAppender.java source code so in setFile() method as below

```
    public
  synchronized
  void setFile(String fileName, boolean append, boolean bufferedIO, int bufferSize)
                                                            throws IOException {
    LogLog.debug("setFile called: "+fileName+", "+append);

    // It does not make sense to have immediate flush and bufferedIO.
    if(bufferedIO) {
      setImmediateFlush(false);
    }

    reset();
    FileOutputStream ostream = null;
    try {
          //
          //   attempt to create file
          //
          ostream = new FileOutputStream(fileName, append);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
          //
          //   if parent directory does not exist then
          //      attempt to create it and try to create file
          //      see bug 9150
          //
          String parentName = new File(fileName).getParent();
          if (parentName != null) {
             File parentDir = new File(parentName);
             if(!parentDir.exists() && parentDir.mkdirs()) {
                ostream = new FileOutputStream(fileName, append);
             } else {
                throw ex;
             }
          } else {
             throw ex;
          }
    }
```

cause the problem means, can multiple threads entering in this method and causing trying to create the file, `causing the race condition.`

Any Kind of help will be appreciable.

Comment: For output files this means the target directory doesn't exist.

Comment: okay, is this issue because of race condition because other test cases are working fine or something else is going on?

Comment: As noted in @PiotrPKarwasz's answer, the race condition involves your redundant call to `exists()` as part of a non-atomic `&&`. You should just remove it and test the result of `mkdirs()`. It has to do the test anyway, and it does so atomically, so no race condition.

Comment: @user207421 I was also thinking in the same manner, but I need to do two things either I change the code of the library or I should create a custom FileAppender of mine, Do you have any idea to solve this issue without doing these things?

Comment: As I said in another comment, I ceased having anything to do with log4j several years ago on their ludicrous security bug. I recommend you follow suit. This bug is yet another reason.

Answer (score 1):

The race condition occurs when evaluating:

```java
if(!parentDir.exists() && parentDir.mkdirs())
```

Your code creates a great amount of `FileAppender`s. What probably happens is:

1. A `FileNotFoundException` is thrown in two threads,
2. One of the threads creates the parent directory and continues successfully,
3. In the other thread `!parentDir.exists()` returns `false` and the exception is rethrown.

**Remark**: the line numbers in your stack trace do not match the version you are using (1.1.3), but they match version 1.2.17. This version has been published more than 10 years ago and Log4j 1.x has reached end-of-life 8 years ago. Consider upgrading to Log4j 2.x.

Comment: If would be best to just remove the `exists()` test and always call `mkdirs()`. That has to test for existence itself anyway, so nothing is lost, and it will tell you whether it did anything or not. And `mkdirs()` is atomic, unlike `&&`. I have personally discontinued all use of `log4j` since the absurd security bug they disclosed a couple of years ago. All these 3rd-party logging packages have really been redundant since Java 1.4 logging, poor as it is.

Comment: That means this race condition is occurring in Log4j library because at my end I am just calling the FileAppender of Log4j and in FileAppender Race condition is occurring, so, in this case, I would need to change the Library code to do everything is better because when I saw the new version of log4j, FileAppender has the same code lines as I have mentioned. Is there any solution with out changing the Library code or custom-creating the FileAppender?

Comment: As mentioned before Log4j 1.x has been dead for more than a decade. You can either: 1. upgrade to version 2.x, 2. sent a PR to [reload4j](https://github.com/qos-ch/reload4j), 3. patch and recompile the library yourself.